# How to create a modified comma separated list using Ansible and an Ansible group as input

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to build up a comma separated list of IP addresses from an Ansible group. So far I have it reading the group and creating the list. My task code so far:

```
  - name: Add IP address of coordinating hosts
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
      regexp: '^(.*)elasticsearch.hosts:(.*)$' 
      line: "elasticsearch.hosts: [{{ groups['coordinating_nodes'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}]"
      state: present
```

This give an output of:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: [192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4]
```

Is there a way to modify each individual map value so that its like:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://192.168.1.1:9200", "https://192.168.1.2:9200", "https://192.168.1.3:9200", "https://192.168.1.4:9200"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `regex_replace` filter to get what you want. Use `map` to apply it to your list of addresses, replacing each address with `https://<the address>:9200`:

```
map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'https://\\1:9200')
```

For example, the following playbook:

```
---
- gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    fake_hostvars:
      foo:
        ansible_default_ipv4:
          address: 1.1.1.1
      bar:
        ansible_default_ipv4:
          address: 2.2.2.2
      baz:
        ansible_default_ipv4:
          address: 3.3.3.3

    coordinating_nodes:
      - foo
      - bar
      - baz

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ coordinating_nodes | map('extract', fake_hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'https://\\1:9200') | list }}]"
```

Will produce:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "['https://1.1.1.1:9200', 'https://2.2.2.2:9200', 'https://3.3.3.3:9200']]"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```